# Ubuntu on virtual machine: ethernet doesn't work Intel Gigabit Ethernet Controller is disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, virtualbox, ethernet

I have a big problem connecting the VM to the network.
I changed network setting on VM to bridged, but whet I use
 `ifconfig -a` I only see `local` and `eth2` (which does not have an IP address)

But when I check what network adapter I have with  `lspci -nnk |grep -i A2 net` and `lshw -class network`  I see `Intel Gigabit Ethernet Controller`, but it's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I solved the problem with these commands:

```
ip link set dev eth2 down
sudo dhclient eth2
```